a white space is left when my viewport is smaller that 998px
I was trying to set up some media querys in my html and css project and all seem to work just fine, but i notice that when i shrink my screen an empty white space is left at the right side of the screen.Also a orizzontal scroll bar appears at the bottom and i dont know why.
I already try to use the overflow:hidden, but it mess up my sticky navbar so i aslo try with overflow:clip but i doesen't seem to work. I am expectin to not see that white extra space also when i open my website on my phone.
FIXED: the problem was that in my css i specified a width whith width:998px; so when i shrink my web browser the medka querys start doing his job and try to shrink everything but the width was pre-imposted in a fixed value so the div were going out of the viewport creating a withe space at the right of my web browser.

Please see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Having said that... On your page, scroll down.  There are images in the footer which are pushing content wider.

thank you so much for your response, i didn't know that you can't link smth in SO i am sorry about that, the more you know...
about your response i already try to shrink the div that contains the placeholder img and i put every div in the corrispective grid
".footer-logo1,
.footer-logo2,
.footer-logo3,
.footer-logo4{
width: 155px;
}
.footer-logo1{
grid-column-start: 1;
}
.footer-logo2{
grid-column-start: 2;
}
.footer-logo3{
grid-column-start: 3;
}
.footer-logo4{
grid-column-start: 4;
}" but this doesn't resolve the problem either

You encountered this situation because of the 150x32 footer-logo in the footer section, if you edit the dimensions, it will be fixed.

hi thank you for your response i try to change the dimension with a 120x30 but the white space is stille there :(

i also try to specify a different width in the img footer like this
".footer-logo1 img,
.footer-logo2 img,
.footer-logo3 img,
.footer-logo4 img{
width: 80%;
}" but i doesen't work either

The problem is the div with the origin class name in the footer section, if you fix it, your problem will be completely fixed.

yes i sees that as i wrote an answer to your comment i am now trying to fix it, i'll let you know. Thank you for your help till here :)

I'd be happy to help you.
